# How to use Omnisharp Server to compile project asynchronously in a VS Code extension?

Tags: omnisharp

I need to compile c# projects from my VS Code extension and extract the emitted binary file. I have found that C# extension install and uses the Omnisharp server for compilation. Is there a way to tap in to the same Omnisharp server to trigger compilation from my VS Code extension?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the official Microsoft documentation for Visual Code + OmniSharp
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/with-visual-studio-code

basically all you need is `dotnet run`